# Function for populating a model data with another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am new to Rails. I have written two models A and B. Models of A and B are like following:

```
 class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible: a1, a2
 end

 class B < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible: b1,b2
   self.table_name = "b"
 end
```

Actually here there is a rake task that will populate the data of A with data of B on daily basis so that from the rake task we can call the function. I cannot understand where to write those functions that will populate the data of A with data from B.

Comment: Do you just want all the data from B replacing the contents of A each day? Or just copy the new data? You might need to clarify. The simplest solution at the moment seems to be to just do it with sql. `A.connection.execute('insert into a (a1, a2) (select b1, b2 from b)')`

Answer (score 1):

You have mentioned that there are some rake tasks. You can put the code inside them, on `lib/tasks` directory. As an example:

**copy_from_b_to_a.rake**

```
namespace :copy do
  task :from_b => :environment do
    B.all.each do |b|
      a = A.new a1 => b1, a2 => b2
      a.save
    end
  end
end
```

If you run `rake -T`, you can see `rake copy:from_b` listed as a task, and when you run it, it would try to copy the data executing the code inside the `.rake` task you created.

That's just a simple example of working with rake tasks.